# Grails Query with parent

Tags: grails

If I have four domain classes like this:

```
class Branch {
    String name
    static hasMany   = [users:Users] 
    static mappedBy  = [users:'branch']   
    static mapping = {                
        id          column: 'f_branch_id'
        name        column: 'f_name'
    }
}
class Users {
    String name
    static hasMany  = [account:Account]
    static mappedBy = [account:'user']
    static belongsTo= [branch:Branch, title:Title]
    static mapping = {
        id          column: 'f_user_id',
        name        column: 'f_name',   
        branch      column: 'k_branch_id'
    }
}
class Account {
    String username   
    static belongsTo   = [user:Users]   
    static mapping = {
        id              column: 'f_account_id'
        user            column: 'f_user_id'
        username        column: 'f_username'
    }
}
class JoinTable implements Serializable {
    Account account
    Role role    
    static mapping = {
        id              composite   : ['role', 'account']
        role            column      :'k_role_id'
        account         column      :'k_account_id'
        version false
    }    
}
```

How can i get branch from JoinTable using criteria query
i try this process but fail for alias problem

```
 def criteria = JoinTable.createCriteria()
     def list = criteria.list {             
         account {
                user{
                    branch{
                        eq("id", "2")
                    }
                }
         }
    }
```

Comment: class Account {
    String username   
    static belongsTo   = [user:Account]   ????? maybe [user:Users]

Comment: Thanks @Andrii Olenchenko but it can not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

**Domains**

```
class Branch {
    String name
    static hasMany   = [users:Users]
    static mapping = {
        id          column: 'f_branch_id'
        name        column: 'f_name'
    }
}
class Title {
    ...
}
class Users {
    String name
    static hasMany  = [account:Account]
    static belongsTo= [branch:Branch, title:Title]
    static mapping = {...}
}
class Account {
    String username
    static belongsTo   = [user:Users]
    static mapping = {...}   
}
class Role {
   ...
}
class JoinTable implements Serializable {
    Account account
    Role role
    static mapping = {
        id              composite   : ['role', 'account']
        role            column      :'k_role_id'
        account         column      :'k_account_id'
        version false
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
@Mock([Act, Branch, Title, Users, Account, Role, JoinTable])
class EaseTests {
void testCriteria(){
        10.times{
            def b = new Branch().save(validate:false, flush:true)
            10.times{ 
                def u = new Users(branch:b).save(validate:false, flush:true) 
                10.times{
                    def a  = new Account(user:u).save(validate:false, flush:true) 
                    def joinTableRow  = new JoinTable(account: a).save(validate:false, flush:true)
                }
            }          
        }    

        def c = JoinTable.createCriteria()
        def results = c{
            account{
                   user {
                       branch{
                           idEq(2l)
                       }
                   }
           }
        }
        assert results
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrii Olenchenko but it can not solve my problem because i seen alias problem

Comment: Thanks @Andrii Olenchenko for your response and i try your procedure
I seen something like this in my app console mode

ERROR: Unknown column 'branch_ali3_.f_branch_id' in 'where clause'

here alies "branch_ali3_" not exist in query